# Why is IE ignoring width, height on inline link tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pre-req:

`<a href="#a" 
onClick="MyWindow=window.open(\'https://<Server IP>/ClickHereNotes.html#<Div Name AAA>\',\'MyWindow\',width=600, height=300); return false;">Click Here.</a>`

By clicking on the link above, the embedded html page is opened but only the target div name AAA is displayed.

Below is the toggle like function I have used in the html `script` tag:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

**Problem:** When the link above is clicked in `Chrome` it opens a popup window, while displaying the whole div html content

When I try to open the link in `IE 11`, the pop up window appears but the window size does not wrap around the html content of the div in concern. There is also no scroll bar.

Things I have tried so far, but did not work:

1. Adding `scrollbar=yes`
2. Adding `min-height`
3. Adding `%` in `width` and `height`.
4. removing `width` and `height`.
5. Adding a `char` after `href=#`.

What property should I use to display the pop up window with complete div HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

add this attribute `Overflow:scroll` to your div

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show a new page with bookmark .
which is possible by Just create CONTENT Will come on top when url with #BookMark1 will

but still another content will show while scrolling .
to make hide this u need to code for java script.

Comment: No. You can display only the target div using url#<div id>. Everything else will be hidden. That feature works perfectly fine. Only issue is that in IE. The size of pop up is not adjustable.

Comment: Try grouping the sizes together. `'width=200, height=200'`

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
div { display: none; } 
div:target { display: block; }
```

and add:

```
html, body{ overflow: auto; }
```

and add 
`scrollbar=yes` 
in tag